# How should I choose the best option for a London apartment rental?

Tags: planning, rental, london, accommodation

I am traveling with two coworkers after our London Dev Days event, and we are looking to rent a local apartment. Knowing very little about London and its various neighborhoods, I am wondering which of the three options below will suit us best (we are three 20-somethings looking for a quaint neighborhood setting offering nearby restaurants, pubs and shopping, within walking distance to the tube)
Options are:

- Slaidburn St in Kensington, England,
- Cheshire St in Poplar, England,
- St John St in Islington, England

Comment: The place in Poplar is the furthest from central London. All those locations have a tube station within a mile. I would recommend Islington over Kensington personally, better bars and cafes for a younger crowd (imo), although neither of them are what I would call "quaint".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Would you have a specific neighborhood that you would recommend that is not on this list? (if you had to choose just one haha)

Comment: If you want to check for nice pubs, then [Beer In The Evening](http://www.beerintheevening.com/) is likely your best bet. Tap in the locations of the apartments, and look for the ones with nice pubs nearby!

Comment: Also my favourite is Putney, but it's a little further out (zone 2/3).  But nice parks, and pubs on the river.

Answer (score 7):

- Kensington is wealthy, central London.
- Poplar is rather far East, near Canary Wharf.
- Islington is a trendy Yuppie residential neighborhood.

The approximate New York City equivalents might be the Upper East Side, Red Hook, and Park Slope, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

I personally would also rate Islington over Kensington - surely it'll be substantially cheaper too.  I prefer south of the river (Putney, Southfields) but you may feel that's too far out.  Poplar is quite a distance and frustrating if you find the DLR line is down.  Islington (and to an extent Kensington) is close enough to walk into town even if buses aren't running (rare).

Let's put it more simply.  If I give it some radius of a couple of miles, of the 20-somethings I know, there'd be 1 in 'Poplar', about 10 in Islington/Angel, and 3 in Kensington.  So my money would be in Islington suiting you the best.